# Css Bootsraps class being addes by my customclass

Tags: css, class, bootstrap-4

I have several tables all about the same size I can add the classes to each one but how do I add multiple Bootstrap classes to apply to one class? IE
`<table class='table table dark>` is how I get my current result

Is there a way to do this in the style sheet for bootstraps styling?

So for every time, I use the "bootstraps" "Table class" I don't have to go to each table and add several classes?
Something like this?

```
.table {

    table:Table;
    table:table-dark;

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand You but if you want to create your own class that will include CSS from multiple Bootstrap classes - then You must check source of Bootstrap.css and create Your own one class ... or use jQuery/JS and always add every <table> tag that same bootstrap classes. ... But why You want to do it? :)

Comment: I assume I need to create my own class. I really just want to add several classes to one class. As in bootstrap has pre-defined classes Ie Table, then you can add table-dark in line what I want to do Is add all the predefined classes on the style sheet into one so I only need to add Class=tabbleAll/

Comment: You can't just "add classes" by name and create ONE YOURS. In SCSS you can create variable but You won't have access to it in html.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the SCSS version of bootstrap: (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/sass/), you could target the tables and `@extend` the classes into your target: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend.

### SCSS

```
.dog {
  color: brown;
}
.bone {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

table {
  @extend .dog;
  @extend .bone;
}
```

### Compiled CSS

```
table {
  color: brown;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

If you aren't using SCSS, then you would probably need to collect all desired styles and place in a single class to add to the tables, or just target all of your tables with your new class.